# 504 Gateway Time-out error when making cURL request in WordPress

Tags: curl

I'm encountering a 504 Gateway Time-out error when attempting to make a cURL request in a WordPress environment. I've included the relevant code below:

```
    function welkvoxapi() {
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://wv{{wolkvox_server}}.wolkvox.com/api/v2/campaign.php?api=add_record&type_campaign={{type_campaign}}&campaign_id={{campaign_id}}&campaign_status={{campaign_status}}',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'[{
            "customer_name": "namewv",
            "customer_last_name": "field_3d8268c",
            "customer_id": "field_d3976af",
            "city": "field_5dd4679",
            "opt1": "field_9f10881",
            "opt3": "field_6d254ff",
            "opt4": "field_363c904",
            "opt5": "field_a5de87f",
            "opt6": "field_dc05404",
            "opt7": "field_9a9a683",
            "opt8": "field_383d50f",
            "email": "field_8981d35"  


}]',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'wolkvox-token: {{token}}'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;


}
add_action('init', 'welkvoxapi');
```

I've added the following cURL code to my WordPress theme's functions.php file to interact with the Wolkvox API. However, when I save the code, the page doesn't load, and I encounter a "504 Gateway Time-out" error.

Wolkvoks [Documentation](https://www.wolkvox.com/en/apis-v2-2/2-1-inserting-records-in-the-campaign-predictive/).

Additionally, I am hosting my WordPress site on AWS, but I'm unsure if this is relevant to the encountered issue.

I have replaced the corresponding information in both the CURLOPT_URL and the token.

I would appreciate any guidance on resolving the "504 Gateway Time-out" issue. Additionally, if there are any considerations or best practices for integrating cURL requests in WordPress, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation wants you to insert the proper values where they use double curly braces.

```
To consume this API you must replace in the url {{{wolkvox_server}} by the nomenclature of the server of the operation.
```

In your particular account, they will give you the values you need to subsitute, meaning the server name, the campaign id, campaign type, etc.